# Need to extract a date from a string using pregmatch

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this string

> Fully furnished self contained 2 bedroom suite just 5 minute walk to UVIC is available for September 1.

now I'm using a pregmatch to extract it: Here is the regex.

```
'/\bavailable\\s(?P<date_available>[?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|immediately]+[\\s\d]+)[st|nd|rd|th]?/i'
```

Currently this regex can extract from a string:

```
Available september 1st.
Available September 2nd
available september 3rd
available september 4th
available sept 1
```

The output example is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => available September 1
    [date_available] => September 1
    [1] => September 1
)
```

But I cannot find a way to extract when the strings are:

```
Available for september 1st.
Available in September 2nd
available since september 3rd
available at september 4th
```

anyone can help me deal with this? thanks

Comment: Can't you just change `available` to `available\s+(for|in|at|since|)\s*` ?

Answer (score 1):

With wildcard A-Z, 2 to 5 letters (matches things like "on"):

```
$regex = '/\bavailable[ ]*(?:[a-z]{2,5})?[ ]*' .
    '(?P<date_available>immediately|now|' .
    '(?:(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?' .
    '|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?' .
    '|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)' .
    '[ ]+[\d]+))' .
    //end <date_available>
    '(?:st|nd|rd|th)?/i';
```

Usage:

```
$lines = array(
    'Fully furnished self contained 2 bedroom suite just 5 minute walk to UVIC is available now.',
    'bedroom suite just 5 minute walk to UVIC is available on September 34.',
    'bedroom suite just 5 minute walk to somewhere is available on Apr 1.',
    );

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo $line, "\n<br>\n";
    if (preg_match($regex, $line, $matches) === 1) {
        print_r($matches['date_available']);
    } else {
        echo "Does not match.";
    }
    echo "\n<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: can you please write the full regex if okay. Just use the regex I provided thank you

Comment: This regex seems good to as well. How about improving it to support:
Available immediately, Available now?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following works with all of your examples, although I haven't put in your 'named sub-patterns' in PHP as I don't know the exact syntax for them

```
\bavailable\s+(?:(?:for|in|at|since)\s+)?((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)
```

Comment: thanks. here is my final regex works with "Available immediately/now" as well. '/\bavailable\s+(for|in|at|since|)\\s*?(?P<date_available>[?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|immediately|now|to]+[\\s\d]+)[st|nd|rd|th]?/i'

Comment: Oh yeah, totally forgot to add those on the end.

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually get yours to work at all, it looks as though you're trying to use character classes with square brackets `[ ]` rather than grouping and alternating with parentheses `( )`.

The following is probably the shortest I can get it based on your requirement

```
$pattern = '/\bavailable\s+(?:(?:for|in|at|since)\s+)?((?:immediately|now)|(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Sept|Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s+?\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)/i';
```

This doesn't include the named sub-pattern as the required match will always be in `$matches[1]` however if you want to include a named subpattern then you can always put one in.

```
$pattern = '/\bavailable\s+(?:(?:for|in|at|since)\s+)?(?P<date_available>(?:immediately|now)|(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Sept|Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s+?\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?)/i';
```

In response to @EthanB earlier solution, you don't seem to be capturing the ordinal suffix for the date `st, nd, rd, th`, if that's the case, and it's not required then you can make it even shorter by not including that, there's no point in trying to match anything after the day number.